# Definition of $[\mathscr A^{\text{op}}, \textbf{Set}](H_A,X)\to [\mathscr A^{\text{op}}, \textbf{Set}](H_B,X)$ in the proof of the Yoneda lemma

Tags: category-theory, proof-explanation, yoneda-lemma

Regarding the [proof](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1612.09375.pdf) of the Yoneda lemma on p.98:

How does one get that the map $$[\mathscr A^{\text{op}}, \textbf{Set}](H_A,X)\to [\mathscr A^{\text{op}}, \textbf{Set}](H_B,X)$$ is defined by $-\circ H_f$
? (The definition of $H_f$ is given on p.90.)

And how does one get that the map $$[\mathscr A^{\text{op}}, \textbf{Set}](H_A,X)\to [\mathscr A^{\text{op}}, \textbf{Set}](H_A,X')$$ is defined by $\theta\circ -$ ?

Comment: That's just applying the definition of what a Hom-functor is on $[\mathscr{A}^{op},\mathbf{Set}]$, unless I'm missing something about your question.

Comment: @MaliceVidrine The hom functor would be $[\mathscr A^{\text{op}}, \textbf{Set}](-,X)$, I think our case is more complicated than that -- I guess the functor is $[\mathscr A^{\text{op}}, \textbf{Set}](H_\bullet,X)$, which is the composition of $H_\bullet$ with $[\mathscr A^{\text{op}}, \textbf{Set}](-,X)$. But I'm still confused: the former functor has codomain $[\mathscr A^{\text{op}}, \textbf{Set}]$, whereas the domain of the latter functor is $[\mathscr A^{\text{op}}, \textbf{Set}]^{op}$, so they cannot be composed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First question. The context is that we want to prove that $$[\mathscr A^{\text{op}}, \textbf{Set}](H_A,X)\cong X(A)$$ naturally in $A$. That is, that the functors $$[\mathscr A^{\text{op}}, \textbf{Set}](H_\bullet,X)\text{ and } X(\bullet)$$ are naturally isomorphic. To see why the map $$[\mathscr A^{\text{op}}, \textbf{Set}](H_A,X)\to [\mathscr A^{\text{op}}, \textbf{Set}](H_B,X)$$ is defined in the way described by Leinster,  we decompose the functor in question viz. $[\mathscr A^{\text{op}}, \textbf{Set}](H_\bullet,X)$ as a composition of two functors. This is implicitly done on p.95 (see the [related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3293066/about-the-naturality-condition-in-the-yoneda-lemma)). The decomposition, according to p.95, is

$$\mathscr A^{op}\to[\mathscr A^{\text{op}}, \textbf{Set}]^{op}\to\mathbf {Set}\\ A\mapsto H_\bullet(A)=H_A\mapsto [\mathscr A^{op},\mathbf{Set}](H_A,X)$$

where the first functor is $H_\bullet^{op}$ and the second functor is $[\mathscr A^{op},\mathbf{Set}](-,X)$.

Here is how the composition works on arrows.

- Let $f:B\to A$ be an arrow in $\mathscr A$ (so that $f^{op}:A\to B$ is an arrow in $\mathscr A^{op}$).
- Under the functor $H_\bullet^{op}:\mathscr A^{op}\to[\mathscr A^{\text{op}}, \textbf{Set}]^{op}$, the arrow $f^{op} $ gets mapped to the arrow $H_\bullet^{op}(f^{op})=H_\bullet(f)^{op}=H_f^{op}:H_A\to H_B$. Here we used Definition 4.1.21 and the definition of the opposite functor.
- Then, under the functor $[\mathscr A^{op},\mathbf{Set}](-,X): [\mathscr A^{\text{op}}, \textbf{Set}]^{op}\to\mathbf {Set}$, the arrow $H_f^{op}$ gets mapped to the arrow $-\circ H_f:[\mathscr A^{op},\mathbf{Set}](H_A,X)\to [\mathscr A^{op},\mathbf{Set}](H_B,X)$. Here we used Definition 4.1.16.

This answers the first question.

For the second question, we are dealing with the functor $[\mathscr A^{op},\mathbf{Set}](H_A,-)$, which is not even a composite functor, so we can directly apply Definition 4.1.1.

Answer (score 1):

For any category $\mathcal C$, the hom functor acts on morphisms by pre- and post composition: if $\alpha:A'\to A$ and $\beta:B\to B'$ are morphisms in $\mathcal C$, then 
$$\mathcal C(\alpha,\beta):\mathcal C(A,B)\to \mathcal C(A', B')\\
\varphi \ \mapsto\ \beta\circ\varphi\circ\alpha$$
And in particular, it's usual to write $\mathcal C(A,\beta)$ for $\mathcal C(1_A,\beta)$ and $\mathcal C(\alpha, B)$ for $\mathcal C(\alpha, 1_B)$.

Apply it with $\mathcal C =[\mathscr A^{op}, \mathbf{Set}]$, $\ \alpha=H_f\ $ and $\ \beta=\theta$.

Comment: I think this answers my second question, but not the first (see my comment above).

Comment: No, it's the same: for $f:A\to B$ in $\mathscr A$ we get $H_f:H_A\to H_B$ (whose $X$ component is just $\mathscr A(X, f)$) and we apply the above with $\alpha =H_f$.

Comment: I still feel such construction sweeps the details under the rug (probably because I don't have much experience with category theory and want to spell out every detail). I posted an answer which looks more plausible for me.

Answer (score 1):

The single argument Hom-functors you're probably more familiar with are just what happens when you fix one of the arguments $\mathcal{C}(-,-):\mathcal{C}^{op}\times\mathcal{C}\to\mathbf{Set}$. As functors with that domain, you can absolutely use both the pre- and post-compositions this proof is talking about.

But I don't think you're quite clear on what the proof is trying to do. It's trying to establish a natural isomorphism between two functors $\mathscr{A}^{op}\times[\mathscr{A}^{op},\mathbf{Set}]\to \mathbf{Set}$. One of these functors is the evaluation functor, but the other is the composite $$\hom\circ (H_{-}\times id):\mathscr{A}^{op}\times[\mathscr{A}^{op},\mathbf{Set}]\to[\mathscr{A}^{op},\mathbf{Set}]^{op}\times[\mathscr{A}^{op},\mathbf{Set}]\to\mathbf{Set}$$ where that "$\hom$" is the two-argument Hom-functor. The first half of the stuff on p.98 is establishing naturality of this isomorphism in the *first* argument, and the second half is establish naturality in the *second* argument. But to talk about the behavior in both arguments of that big composite above is precisely to talk about instances of both pre- and post-composition.

Comment: I asked a separate question about the composite functor you (and Leinster) are referring to: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3293066/about-the-naturality-condition-in-the-yoneda-lemma